# WordPress Not Rendering HTML5 Video

Tags: php, html, wordpress, video

I am trying to create a splash page in WordPress (which I have done), but the video I would like to play isn't being located by the browser.

This works when not in WordPress.  But once inside WordPress, it's not.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Splash
*/
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Iron Triangle Films Splash Page</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.">
    <style>
   .mainContent{
       width: 50%;
       margin-left: 250px;
   }
   </style>
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="mainContent">
 <video id="my_video" height="500" width="700" autoplay>
 <source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?> itf.mp4"   type="video/mp4">
  <source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?> itf.ogv" type="video/ogg">
   <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
 </video>

 <p style="text-align: center;">This site is currently under development and will be back online shortly.</p>
  </div><!--End Main Content div-->
 </body>
</html>
```

The following line of code in the video source:

```
            <?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>
```

Was suggested by someone, but this did not work.

The site is www.irontrianglefilms.com

I'd appreciate your assistance this is day#2 trying to tackle this issue. 
Chris Mazzochi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one, remember to add the "/" after calling the functions to get a directory.

```
   <?php
/*
Template Name: Splash
*/
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Iron Triangle Films Splash Page</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.">
    <style>
   .mainContent{
       width: 50%;
       margin-left: 250px;
   }
   </style>
  </head>
<body>
 <div class="mainContent">
 <video id="my_video" height="500" width="700" autoplay>
 <source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/itf.mp4"   type="video/mp4">
  <source src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory');?>/itf.ogv" type="video/ogg">
   <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
 </video>

 <p style="text-align: center;">This site is currently under development and will be back online shortly.</p>
  </div><!--End Main Content div-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Tomás, but unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: @ChrisMazzochi, you added a point between the call to `get_bloginfo` and the "/". Also, you have caching activated, so in order to see the changes without flushing the cache add a dummy paramenter, like this: www.irontrianglefilms.com/?cache=324235

Comment: I took that dot/point out of the code.  I don't know why it was still showing.  In any case, with our without the dot, it still doesn't work.

Comment: For me it's working, you have to change the number of the parameter. Also, flush the cache when you finish. Good luck.

Comment: If you don't mind and have a moment, what do you mean regarding changing the number of the parameter? Each time I enter the url I have to do this? I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: No, now just flush the cache. That's all.

Comment: Hitting "Delete Cache" from the dashboard, isn't working.  When I I check Firefox on the machine I wrote the splash file on , it works now in Firefox only.  However, when I go to another computer, and check it in Firefox, I get nothing.  And it's not working on Chrome, Safari or IE.

Comment: You could try to delete folder that WP Super Cache creates. irontrianglefilms.com/wp-content/cache/

Comment: When I did that, and I try to go to the site, I am now prompted to download an "application/x-gzip" file.

Comment: I just deleted/removed completely the WP Super Cache plugin and now it seems to be working.  I'm unclear as to why.  And now I have to figure out what to use to cache correctly.

Comment: Yeah, you should read the docs a bit. But now you could reactivate it and it should work. I think W3 Total Cache is more consistent, at least in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tomás.  It's been a minute since I've worked with WordPress, but I will definitely read up on caching and check out the W3 Total Cache plugin.  Have a good one.